# Tag MP3 downloaded From Internet?

Tags: iphone, xcode, tags, mp3, podcast

I am building an app with several podcasts.  Each podcast gives the option to download the MP3 to the app.  I have about 6 podcasts and would like to Tag each, so that when the archive view is clicked from each podcast, only archived files from that particular podcast show.

Is there someway that I can add a Tag or something to the downloaded mp3, and then in the archive, search only for mp3s with a tag related to that podcast?

BTW, I am using NSURLConnection to download each file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be looking at this in the wrong way.

Rather than tagging your downloaded files, you could set up a data structure to hold information about your files and use that to display your information.

For example. If I were doing this I would have a Core Data model that held information about the downloaded file, and tags, or sources, and I would store the path to that file in the database. That way, you can store whatever information you like about the downloaded file, and you can access it through it's path.